# How to get started with lodash-php

Tags: php, lodash

Im very familiar with lodash, and so I wanted to use lodash-php (https://github.com/lodash-php/lodash-php) however, Im having difficulty getting it to work.

Im not using composer as it suggest. Im just using native php.

I tried running
`include_once '../lib/lodash-php/Lodash.php';` at the top of my script by that isnt working.

When I run the following code nothing happens, no error, no output

```
$option = find($result->options[0]->calls,  function($o) {
  global $value; 
  echo $o->strike->raw.".".$value["strike"];
  return $o->strike->raw ==$value["strike"]; 
});
```

When I run this I get an error

```
$option = _::find($result->options[0]->calls,  function($o) {
  global $value; 
  echo $o->strike->raw.".".$value["strike"];
  return $o->strike->raw ==$value["strike"]; 
});
```

`Function _::find is not valid`

So obviously its not importing the functions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

While technically, it is possible, to use the library without composer, it is not recommended as it will be a lot harder to include all the dependencies.

For example, this project uses the symfony/property-access package, so you will need to manually include that with all the relevant files in your project.

Also, you will need to include the entire library at once, as there are a lot of internal functions split over multiple files, so if you only include, for example, the file src/Collection/map.php, it won't just work out of the box since you need to require the internal functions as well.